# how can i read and write data in each sheet of a workbook in java using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, selenium

Here is a method below that i am using. It is able to read/write on the first sheet of workbook but for all the others available sheets its not doing that.
Find below the code :

```
public void ResetExecutionStatus(String logpath , String columnName)
{
    boolean isPresent = false;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File(logpath));
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);

        int x = workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int n=1; n<x; n++)
        {

        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(n);
        System.out.println("Sheet Name: "+sheet.getSheetName());

        for (int i=0; i<sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
        {
        Row r = sheet.getRow(i);
        System.out.println("Value of i: "+i);
        for (int cn=0; cn<r.getLastCellNum(); cn++)
          {
            Cell c = r.getCell(cn);
            String text = c.getStringCellValue();
            if(columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(text))
            {
                System.out.println("Column Name: "+text);
                for(int a = i+1 ; a <sheet.getLastRowNum(); a++)
                {
                    Row p = sheet.getRow(a);
                    Cell q = p.getCell(cn);
                    String CurrentStatus = q.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println("Current Status: "+CurrentStatus);
                    if(CurrentStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS") || CurrentStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL") || CurrentStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("ON HOLD"))
                    {
                        q .setCellValue("NOT EXECUTED");
                    }
                }

                isPresent = true;
            }
            if(isPresent){break;}
          }
         if(isPresent){break;}  
        }

      }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(logpath));
        workBook.write(out);

        out.close();
        fs.close();
        System.out.println("Data has been reset for Column Name : " +columnName );
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

And the main method is :

```
public class TestCall {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path = "C:\\Users\\abcdef\\Desktop\\ManualLog\\TestLog.xlsx";
    clearLog ob = new clearLog();

    ob.ResetExecutionStatus(path, "Execution Status");


}

}
```

The result in console is :

> Sheet Name: Sheet1
>   Value of i: 0
>   Value of i: 1
>   Value of i: 2
>   Value of i: 3
>   Value of i: 4
>   Column Name: Execution Status
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: NOT EXECUTED
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Current Status: 
>   Sheet Name: Sheet2
>   Value of i: 0
>   Sheet Name: Sheet3
>   Value of i: 0
>   Sheet Name: Sheet4
>   Value of i: 0
>   Data has been reset for Column Name : Execution Status

Comment: It is able to set "NOT EXECUTED" in all the cells of first sheet of the workbook for which previous available data is PASS or FAIL or ON HOLD, but for other sheets nothing is happening.

Comment: You set `isPresent` to `true` in the inner loop... this then causes the code to break out of the outer loops.

Comment: Not sure what u exactly mean.   AS , if(isPresent){break;} is just breaking the inner loops and not the outer most loop which is taking the control to next sheet.

Comment: In [Workbook.getSheetAt(int index)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheetAt(int)) the index is 0 based. So `.getSheetAt(1)` will get the **second** sheet. You will never get the first sheet since `n` starts with 1.

Comment: that is meant to be like that only, as i don't need to do any change in the first sheeet, the issue is, why its not making the changes for all the sheets after first sheet.

Comment: i mean to say that, i dont want to edit sheet0, so i initialized i to 1. Now the code is making desired changes in sheet1 , but not for any sheet after that.

Comment: Seems as if `if(columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(text))` will never be true for `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4`. The sheets itself are reached according to your result in console.

Comment: please have a look into the console output:

Comment: Try `for (int n=1; n<x; n++) { isPresent = false; ...` since `isPresent` is always `true` after proceeding the first (second) sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked